# MS Excel- extract special character from a cell

Tags: excel

I have an excel with one column (say column A) having different data in no specific format. Some of the cells in the column contains some special characters too. I need to find which cell contains "*", "@", "_" and "!". and publish those characters in column B.

For example

```
Column A contains-
A1- ABVC_KL.....
A2- !1223.....
A3- UIL%%$00.....
A4- JOHN@456.....
A5- 9_90*YY!P.....
```

Then, the formula in column B should give this result in column B:

```
B1- _.....
B2- !.....
B3- null.....
B4- @.....
B5- _*!.....
```

Can someone help me with ths?

Comment: have you tried anything? If so, show us your efforts.

Comment: Since you only have four special characters to find, you can use nested `IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(...` within a `CONCAT` or `CONCATENATE` function.

Comment: Scott, I used a very basic method. For each character I need to search, i used two columns. 
So, if column A has the data, in column B I used the following formula =FIND ("_", A1,1),
Then used the following formula in column C= MID(A1,B1,1).

This set of formukla I repeated for each character. But, thats a long process. 
So, wondering if in one cell, I can get all special characters.

Answer (score 1):

For each character you want to find, create a new column (you can hide/group them afterwards), and create a formula like `=IFERROR( IF(SEARCH("!",A2)>0,TRUE),"")`.
If you have a lot of character to check for, reference the string you want to search for from row 1 (example) like this `=IFERROR( IF(SEARCH(B$1,$A2)>0,TRUE),"")`. This way you can copy the formula and it will always reference column A text values and row 1 string values to find.

This will search for the string "!" in cell A2 and give its location. You dont need to know the exact location, just if there is a character like this, so IF >0 provides a TRUE value if there is a "!" anywhere. If there is none, an error is displayed and turned into an empty string "" with the IFERROR().

Comment: I used a very basic method. For each character I need to search, i used two columns. 
So, if column A has the data, in column B I used the following formula =FIND ("_", A1,1),
Then used the following formula in column C= MID(A1,B1,1).

This set of formukla I repeated for each character. But, thats a long process. 
So, wondering if in one cell, I can get all special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try below formula.

=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(G2),"a",),"b",),"c",),"d",),"e",),"f",),"g",),"h",),"i",),"j",),"k",),"l",),"m",),"n",),"o",),"p",),"q",),"r",),"s",),"t",),"u",),"v",),"w",),"x",),"y",),"z",),"0",),"1",),"2",),"3",),"4",),"5",),"6",),"7",),"8",),"9",)